# Using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 and DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding for Android 4.2 and older

Tags: java, android, security, hash, pbkdf2

In my Android application, I would like to encrypt passwords with DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding, my solution works from Lollipop(5.x),Android KitKat(4.4.x) and Android Jelly Bean(4.3.x )

```
private static final String KEY = "a2[..]";
private static final String SALT = "t[..]";
private static final String IV = "u[..]";
private static final String DES_EDE_PKCS5 = "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding"

public static String encrypt(String password) {
    byte[] byteSalt = Base64.decode(SALT, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] bytesIv = Base64.decode(IV, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String mdp = "";        
    try {           
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");          
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(KEY.toCharArray(), byteSalt, NB_ITER_RFC, SIZE_KEY);          
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);             
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(DES_EDE_PKCS5);           
        IvParameterSpec ivParam = new IvParameterSpec(bytesIv);         
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParam);                
        byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        mdp = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);                 
    }
    catch [..]
    return mdp;
}
```

But it's doesn't work for below version (4.2.x and below), this encrypted password seems to change randomly for exemple :

```
D/andro-Chiffrement-encrypt(10739): password chiffré = P7vWc+7hFuUaWQghVeO+zA==
D/andro-Chiffrement-encrypt(10739): password chiffré = jGr6nlvnYLd/AK/d7nkUrA==
D/andro-Chiffrement-encrypt(10739): password chiffré = I2weyEddIav7EulAiuQDbg==
D/andro-Chiffrement-encrypt(10739): password chiffré = HF7OFpUXYuwOm81WekReDg==
```

How can I solve this problem for Android 4.2.x especially ?

I found that with library Bouncy Castle, but I didn't found how to implement 'IV' (Generator Vector). Do you have an idea ?

```
PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator gen = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator();
gen.init(PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS12PasswordToBytes(passCharArray), byteSalt, NB_ITER_RFC);
KeyParameter params = (KeyParameter) gen.generateDerivedParameters(SIZE_KEY);
String password2 = Base64.encodeToString(params.getKey(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 4.4 the SecretKeyFactory API changed. Maybe this could help:

> In Android 4.3 and earlier platform versions, the javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory implementation of  the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 key-generation algorithm only uses the lower 8 bits of Java characters in passphrases. In Android 4.4, the algorithm is changed to use all available bits in Unicode characters, in compliance with recommendations in PCKS #5.
>
> This change could affect applications that use symmetric encryption and meet all of the following conditions:
>   1. Use SecretKeyFactory to generate symmetric keys, and
>   2. Use PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 as their key-generation algorithm for SecretKeyFactory, and
>   3. Allow Unicode input for passphrases

Here the original article:

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/fTY97ekzn6Z

And here you can read about changes to SecretKeyFactory Api:

http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2013/12/changes-to-secretkeyfactory-api-in.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally my solution works for Android 4.3.x but not for Android 4.2.x and below. I corrected my post. This solution doesn't work for me, it's really weird... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this solution : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html

it's due to PRNG (Pseudo Random Number Generator)but this solution has no effect...

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {    

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {        
        PRNGFixes.apply(); [..]
    }
}
```